# Manipulating constants inside the Exponential Integral function

Tags: special-functions

In the following form of the Exponential Integral function;

$$ E_{n}(x+c) $$

where $E_{n}(x+c)$ is the exponential integral function, $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ , $n\in\mathbb{N}$ , $c$ is a constant

Is it possible to take out the constant part $c$ from the function?
If yes, How?

Comment: You mean $\mbox{E}_n(x) = \int_1^\infty e^{-xt}/t^n\, dt$?

Comment: @mvw Yes, it is correct.